# how to get the running time of a hard disk with C/C++

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In Linux, I want to get Hard Disk's Power On Hours with c++?
Can someone tell me which API should be used?

Comment: What's a "hdd usage time"?

Answer (score 0):

you could call [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org) e.g. smartctl and parse the output or do some research which libs or kernel apis it uses itself